# Web scraping through Selenium only loads the skeleton of the page and does not populate the data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am developing a python/selenium script to scrape publicly available data on a website.

Within the website, there is "Search" button, when clicked should bring out 100s of search results.

However, upon initiating a click through selenium, only the skeleton of the search results are loaded, and the actual data is never populated into the skeleton.

[image]

When I check the network tab in chrome console, the data is being fetched perfectly, it is just not being populated onto the webpage

[image]

The console logs throw this error:

```
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D8D67D12+55474]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8CD77C2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8B8E0EB]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8BCEBAC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8BCED2C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8C09F77]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8BEF19F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8C07EF2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8BEEF33]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8BC3D41]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8BC4F84]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D90CB762+3609346]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D9121A80+3962400]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D9119F0F+3930799]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D8E03CA6+694342]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8CE2218]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8CDE484]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8CDE5B2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D8CCEE13]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB49117614+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB4A3026B1+33]
```

I have tried to make the script go to sleep for 10,20,30,60,120 seconds. Yet the page keeps showing me a skeleton state and fails to populate the data.

Moving forward the script tries to extra data from the search results, and I have tried using `WebDriverWait` to wait for element's existence or visibility on the web page.

Some other posts suggested adding header to the chrome driver, that too did not produce desired results.

All of this results in skeleton loading state and then times out with the error in the console as mentioned above.

Note of Interest: The script works perfectly fine on some devices, however it fails to run on certain other devices which has been documented [here](https://github.com/wimpywarlord/appliFLY/issues)

The code base for the script can be found [here](https://github.com/wimpywarlord/appliFLY/tree/main/assets/script) , might be super easy to duplicate the said issue in your local if you run the script.

Comment: Please post the code here, directly in the question.  Don't make us visit some external link.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.